# fgets to include text after newline

Tags: c, input, format, fgets, getline

I want to make an array of characters and store the whole input in it(even if the input contains "\n" at some point. When i use:

```
char vhod[50];

fgets(vhod, sizeof(vhod), stdin);
```

it stores the input UNTIL the first newline. How to get the whole text in this array(including the text after the new line).
Example:
if my text is:

```
Hello I need new keyboard.
This is not good.
```

my array will only contain `"Hello I need new keyboard."`. I want to be able to read everything till the end of input a < input-1
I cannot use FILE open/close/read functions since it is input from keyboard.

Comment: What makes you think you can't use `read()` when the input is from the keyboard?

Comment: You don't have to call `open()`, since standard input is already open.

Comment: If you're using the standard I/O library, then `fread()` is the obvious choice, rather than the file descriptor function `read()`.  Of course, you'll need to be careful not to overflow the buffer; 50 characters is rather small.  Or you can use `fgets()` incrementally; or you could consider POSIX function [`getdelim()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) (a near relative of `getline()`), passing a character such as `'\0'` as the 'line delimiter' so it reads everything up to a null byte or EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `fgets()` is designed to read up to a `'\n'` character or the specified number of bytes, you can use [`fread()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html)<sup>1</sup> instead, like this

```
size_t count = fread(vhod, 1, sizeof(vhod), stdin);
```

and count will contain the number of items read, which in this case is the same as the number of bytes since you are providing size `1` i.e. `sizeof(char)`.

Note however that you must be very careful to add a terminating `'\0'` if you are going to use any function that assumes a terminating `'\0'`.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Read the manual for more information.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didnt know that fread is able to get everything